# janusgraph-0.5.3 memory configuration

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using janusgraph-0.5.3 (with Cassandra) and I want to know how to configure memory allocation to increase default memory allocated to 2GB for the gremlin server process.

I am trying to load bulk data on my gremlin-server, but it is failing with error. I would like to know if there is a way to check and increase the default memory allocation.

I need help in locating the `.yaml` configuration files as well as the values in these files that would need to change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I changed gremlin-server.sh file to take additional memory

```sh
# Set Java options
if [ "$JAVA_OPTIONS" = "" ] ; then
   echo "Setting xmx and xss"
    JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx3074m -Xss2048k -javaagent:$JANUSGRAPH_LIB/jamm-0.3.0.jar -Dgremlin.io.kryoShimService=org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoShimService"
fi
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does? and how much memory it gives to the JanusGraph process? Will this work with other configurations besides Cassandra?